Will taxes from RRIF after age 71 always be less than GIS money?
I hold enough savings to max out my RRSP, so disregard the loan on page 19 of this PDF dated October 2024. But check for latest version.


Mary will pay higher taxes after she turns 71, because she will be getting money from her RRIF. But the taxes will be far less than the extra money she got from GIS for 6 years.
Mary will not qualify for GIS after she turns 71 because her income
will be too high and she can no longer make RRSP contributions.
However, Mary could collect as much as $30,000 in GIS for 6 years,
all because she contributed to an RRSP.
Plus, during those years, Mary saved on taxes.


My figures differ, so don't answer using hypothetical Mary's amounts. In general, will taxes after 71 from RRIF (Registered Retirement Income Fund) always be less than GIS (Guaranteed Income Supplement) money?
Any possibility for taxes after 71 from RRIF to outstrip (>) GIS money?

I added some more context; having read the PDF, I understand the question is predicated on having taken an RRSP loan early in retirement in order to reduce taxable income and  therebyqualify for some GIS payments, when one would not have otherwise qualified for any GIS payments.

@ChrisW.Rea thanks. I deleted loans, as I don't need one.

It's going to depend on Mary's income. If it's extremely high she can pay 46% on the top part of that income. She only has to take $20,000 out of her RRIF for the taxes on that to be higher than the $8700 she gets from OAS. Also note that OAS is deliberately designed to give money to those with a low income. If Mary has a high income she shouldn't be surprised that she doesn't get it. Where is Mary's other income coming from? Is she still working? Does she have investments? If working, does she expect to stop?
